# QDBusConnection error while building qt5 xcb plugin

Tags: qt, xcb

I've been searching for a while here, but I assume I could've missed the answer, in this case please accept my apologies.

[Preconditions]

I built Qt 5.3.1 from source, but missed the fact ./configure script hadn't included xcb plugin. Of course I need it badly now in order to build a qt5 project.

[Problem]

I found it's possible to build plugin separately (I don't want to re-install Qt).
I've been struggling for several days and now I have only one problem:

bridge_p.h:66:5: error: ‘QDBusConnection’ does not name a type
QDBusConnection dBusConnection() const;

View [Make log](http://pastebin.com/u5seQHaY)

Please suggest a solution, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

OK I'm stupid, re-configuration and installing some missing packages helped to solve the error.
New errors are not connected with dbus => this questions is done and dead.